# Autodesk FORGE BIM 360 API - Can't PATCH User

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to update the status of a BIM 360 user (active/inactive) and its Company using the Node.js 'forge-api' package.

This particular endpoint is not available yet in the current api:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-:user_id-PATCH/

Based on implemented endpoints (patchItem) I duplicated it and modified as follows:

```
const { ApiClient } = require('forge-apis');

function patchUser(accountId, oauthClient, credentials, res, userId, companyId, status) {

     const body = {
         status: status,
         company_id: companyId
    }

    patchAPI(accountId, {}, oauthClient, credentials, body, userId)
        .then(data => {
            const { name, id, status, company_name } = data.body
            res.json({name: name, id: id, status: status, company: company_name})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.json(error)
        })

}

async function patchAPI(hubId, opts, oauth2client, credentials, body, userId) {
    opts = opts || {};
    var postBody = body;

    // verify the required parameter 'hubId' is set
    if (hubId == undefined || hubId == null) {
        return Promise.reject("Missing the required parameter 'hubId' when calling patchAPI with users");
    }

    // verify the required parameter 'userId' is set
    if (userId == undefined || userId == null) {
        return Promise.reject("Missing the required parameter 'userId' when calling  patchAPI with users");
    }

    // verify the required parameter 'body' is set
    if (body == undefined || body == null) {
        return Promise.reject("Missing the required parameter 'body' when calling patchAPI with users");
    }

    var pathParams = {
        'hub_id': hubId,
        'user_id': userId
    };
    var queryParams = {};
    var headerParams = {
        'x-user-id': opts.xuserid
    };
    var formParams = {};

    var contentTypes = ['application/vnd.api+json'];
    var accepts = ['application/vnd.api+json', 'application/json'];
    var returnType = null;

    return ApiClient.instance.callApi(
        '/hq/v1/accounts/{hub_id}/users/{user_id}', 'PATCH',
        pathParams, queryParams, headerParams, formParams, postBody,
        contentTypes, accepts, returnType, oauth2client, credentials
    );

}
```

Unfortunately it is not modifying the user. The user is returned exactly as before, as if the Body part is completely ignored.

I know that all my Ids are correct because I receive a status 200 and user is returned (unchanged) and I can successfully PATCH the user with Postman.

Not sure what I am missing but any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PATCH endpoints that are provided in the 'forge-apis' package are for the Data Management API and their Content-Type for the body must be 'application/vnd.api+json'

However for the BIM 360 API the Content-Type must be 'application/json'.
After changing the line below everything is working fine.

`var contentTypes = ['application/json'];`